# Send and receive data to ZeroMQ socket from outside cluster using load balancer kubernetes

Tags: c++, kubernetes, networking, zeromq, metallb

I have a service that is using a load-balancer in order to expose externally a certain IP. I am using metallb because my cluster is bare metal.

This is the configuration of the service: [image]

Inside of the cluster the application running perform a binding to a zmq socket (TCP type) like:

```
m_zmqSock->bind(endpoint);
```

where `endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:1234` and

```
m_zmqSock = std::make_unique<zmq::socket_t>(*m_zmqContext,zmq::socket_type::pair);
m_zmqSock->setsockopt(ZMQ_RCVTIMEO,1);
```

Then from an application in my local computer (with access to the cluster) I am trying to connect and send data like:

```
zmqSock->connect(zmqServer);
```

where `zmqServer = tcp://192.168.49.241:1234` and

```
zmq::context_t ctx;
auto zmqSock = std::make_unique<zmq::socket_t>(ctx,zmq::socket_type::pair);
```

Any idea on how could I make the zmq socket connect from my host to send data to the application and receive response also?

Answer (score 0):

> ***Q:** "Any idea on how could I make the zmq socket connect from my host to send data to the application and receive response also?"*

Welcome to ZeroMQ - let's sketch a work-plan:

1. let's prove the ZeroMQ can be served with an end-to-end visibility working:

- for doing this, use `PUSH-PULL` pattern, being fed from the cluster-side by a `aPushSIDE->send(...)` with regularly spaced timestamped messages, using also a resources saving setup there, using `aPushSIDE->setsockopt( ZMQ_COMPLETE,... )` and `aPushSIDE->setsockopt( ZMQ_CONFLATE,... )`

2. once you can confirm your `localhost`'s `PULL`-end `recv()`-s regular updates, feel free to also add an up-stream link from localhost towards the cluster-hosted code, again using a `PUSH-PULL` pattern in the opposite direction.

Why a pair of `PUSH-PULL`-s here?

First, it helps isolate the root-cause of the problem. Next, it allows you to separate concerns and control each of the flows independently of any other ( details on control loops with many interconnects, with different flows, different priority levels and different error handling procedures are so common to all have exclusively only the non-blocking forms of the `recv()`-methods & doing multi-level `poll()`-methods' soft-control of the maximum permitted time spent ( wasted ) on testing a new message arrival go beyond of the scope of this Q/A text - feel free to seek further in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224179/zmq-socket-gracefully-termination-in-python/26224507#26224507) formal event-handling framing and about using low-level socket-monitor [diagnostics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010505/network-diagnostics-for-zeromq-example/58011275#58011275) )

Last, but not least, the `PAIR-PAIR` archetype used to be reported in ZeroMQ native API documentation as ***"experimental"*** for the most of my ZeroMQ-related life ( since v2.1, yeah, so long ). Accepting that fact, I never used a `PAIR` archetype on any other Transport Class but for a pure-in-RAM, network-protocol stack-less `inproc:` *"connections"* ( that are not actually any connections, but a Zero-Copy, <sub>*almost*</sub> Zero-Latency smart pure pointer-to-memory-block passing trick among some of a same-process co-operating threads ).